# Proguard for Wire + Retrofit NoSuchMethodException

Tags: android, proguard, retrofit2, android-proguard, square-wire

My brain is fried. I searched S.O. for help but it seems Proguard issues with this exception are specific to the app in question. I've been trying to use Proguard to obfucate/minify my app and when I run it in the Generated APK form my app either crashes or hits me with:

```
com.company.project E/a: java.lang.NoSuchMethodException: fromValue [int]
```

Stacktrace:

```
java.lang.AssertionError: java.lang.NoSuchMethodException: fromValue [int]
     at com.squareup.wire.RuntimeEnumAdapter.decode(Unknown Source)
     at com.squareup.wire.RuntimeEnumAdapter.getFromValueMethod(Unknown Source)
     at com.squareup.wire.RuntimeEnumAdapter.decode(Unknown Source)
     at com.company.project.utils.wiremodels.d.a(Unknown Source)
     at com.company.project.utils.wiremodels.d.decode(Unknown Source)
     at com.company.project.utils.wiremodels.g.a(Unknown Source)
     at com.company.project.utils.wiremodels.g.decode(Unknown Source)
     at com.squareup.wire.ProtoAdapter.decode(Unknown Source)
     at retrofit2.converter.wire.WireResponseBodyConverter.convert(Unknown Source)
     at retrofit2.converter.wire.WireResponseBodyConverter.convert(Unknown Source)
     at retrofit2.ServiceMethod.toResponse(Unknown Source)
     at retrofit2.OkHttpCall.parseResponse(Unknown Source)
     at retrofit2.OkHttpCall$1.onResponse(Unknown Source)
     at a.az.b(Unknown Source)
     at a.a.l.run(Unknown Source)
     at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1113)
     at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:588)
     at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:818)
 Caused by: java.lang.NoSuchMethodException: fromValue [int]
     at java.lang.Class.getMethod(Class.java:624)
     at java.lang.Class.getMethod(Class.java:603)
    ... 18 more
```

My app uses Retrofit (2.1.0) and Wire, both from Square. Then when my app crashes I'm checking the `mapping.txt` file to see what class is causing the issue (I believe it's `com.company.project.a`, right?)

Anyway here's my proguard file (with obscure class names fyi):

```
-dontwarn okio.**
-dontwarn retrofit2.Platform$Java8
-dontwarn retrofit2.**
-keep class retrofit2.** { *; }
-keep class com.squareup.wire.** { *; }
-keep class com.company.project.utils.wiremodels.ProtoFile1 { *; }
-keep class com.company.project.utils.wiremodels.ProtoFile2 { *; }
-keep class com.company.project.utils.wiremodels.ProtoFile3 { *; }
-keep class com.company.project.utils.wiremodels.ProtoFile4 { *; }
-keep class com.company.project.utils.wiremodels.ProtoFile5 { *; }
-dontwarn com.google.**
-keepattributes Signature
-keepattributes *Annotation*
-keepattributes Exceptions
-dontwarn org.w3c.dom.bootstrap.DOMImplementationRegistry
-dontwarn org.simpleframework.xml.stream.**
```

It would be amazing if I can get some help with this, please let me know if there's more info I should provide.

EDIT: Question answered in the comments of marked answer (for future references)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can keep methods in some classes with :

```
-keepclassmembers,allowobfuscation class com.company.project.yourClass.** {
    <methods>;
}
```

As you are using `wire`, form [these indications](http://github.com/square/wire#generating-code-with-wire) proguard recommended is :

```
-keep class com.squareup.wire.** { *; }
-keep class com.yourcompany.yourgeneratedcode.** { *; }
```

If the problem is coming from `retrofit` [here is a proguard example](https://github.com/krschultz/android-proguard-snippets/blob/master/libraries/proguard-square-retrofit.pro) :

```
-keep class com.squareup.okhttp.** { *; }
-keep class retrofit.** { *; }
-keep interface com.squareup.okhttp.** { *; }

-dontwarn com.squareup.okhttp.**
-dontwarn okio.**
-dontwarn retrofit.**
-dontwarn rx.**

-keepclasseswithmembers class * {
    @retrofit.http.* <methods>;
}

# If in your rest service interface you use methods with Callback argument.
-keepattributes Exceptions

# If your rest service methods throw custom exceptions, because you've defined an ErrorHandler.
-keepattributes Signature
```

Comment: is there anyway I could use that to prevent the `NoSuchMethodException`? The logs aren't specific enough to know what method is being looked for

Comment: add it to your proguard file with the class name containing the annoying method to see if it helps

Comment: sigh, no luck... next error I got was `java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Unable to create converter for class com.company.project.d.a.h` (Think it's referring to Retrofit's converter for the Wire response)

Comment: Did you try to add  `-keep class com.squareup.wire.** { *; }` and `-keep class com.yourcompany.yourgeneratedcode.** { *; }` as referred in https://github.com/square/wire#generating-code-with-wire ?

Comment: yes it actually worked (instead of having proguard keep each seperate generated file like I have in the question). But there's another issue involving SimpleXML with Proguard. I guess I'll open up another SO question for that after some more research.